# How to count consecutive numbers in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

If I have an array:

```
array = [1,2,2,2,2,5,5,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

I want to be able to identify consecutive matching numbers that have a length of greater than 3. And map the starting index of the consecutive numbers. An example output for the above array would be:

```
consecutive_numbers = [
  {starting_index: 1, value: 2, length: 4},
  {starting_index: 10, value: 3, length: 4},
  {starting_index: 14, value: 2, length: 7}
]
```

The values can be the same, but the consecutive series' must be mutually exclusive. See that there are 2 hashes with a value of 2, but their starting indexes are different.

My attempt so far... looks like this:

```
array.each_cons(3).with_index.select{|(a,b,c), i| 
  [a,b,c].uniq.length == 1
}
```

but that will returns:

```
[[[2, 2, 2], 1], [[2, 2, 2], 2], [[1, 1, 1], 7], [[3, 3, 3], 10], [[3, 3, 3], 11], [[2, 2, 2], 14], [[2, 2, 2], 15], [[2, 2, 2], 16], [[2, 2, 2], 17], [[2, 2, 2], 18]]
```

But that returns overlapping results.

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself?

Comment: @Loocid Yes, thanks for asking, I've added it to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array.each_with_index.
      chunk(&:first).
      select { |_,a| a.size > 3 }.
      map { |n,a| { starting_index: a.first.last, value: n, length: a.size } }
  #=> [{:starting_index=> 1, :value=>2, :length=>4},
  #    {:starting_index=>10, :value=>3, :length=>4},
  #    {:starting_index=>14, :value=>2, :length=>7}]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
e = array.each_with_index.chunk(&:first)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00005b1944253c18>:each>
```

We can convert this enumerator to an array to view the elements it will generate and pass to its block.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[1, [[1, 0]]],
  #    [2, [[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]],
  #    [5, [[5, 5], [5, 6]]],
  #    [1, [[1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9]]],
  #    [3, [[3, 10], [3, 11], [3, 12], [3, 13]]],
  #    [2, [[2, 14], [2, 15], [2, 16], [2, 17], [2, 18], [2, 19], [2, 20]]]]
```

Continuing,

```
c = e.select { |_,a| a.size > 3 }
  #=> [[2, [[2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]],
  #    [3, [[3, 10], [3, 11], [3, 12], [3, 13]]],
  #    [2, [[2, 14], [2, 15], [2, 16], [2, 17], [2, 18], [2, 19], [2, 20]]]] 
c.map { |n,a| { starting_index: a.first.last, value: n, length: a.size } }
  #=> [{:starting_index=> 1, :value=>2, :length=>4},
  #    {:starting_index=>10, :value=>3, :length=>4},
  #    {:starting_index=>14, :value=>2, :length=>7}]
```

This is another way.

```
array.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(n,i),arr|
  if arr.any? && arr.last[:value] == n
    arr.last[:length] += 1
  else
    arr << { starting_index: i, value: n, length: 1 }
  end
end.select { |h| h[:length] > 3 }
  #=> [{:starting_index=> 1, :value=>2, :length=>4},
  #    {:starting_index=>10, :value=>3, :length=>4},
  #    {:starting_index=>14, :value=>2, :length=>7}]
```

Comment: `.each_with_object([])` in this case is just `map`

Comment: @engineersmnky, thank you for informing me of my blind spot.

Answer (score 2):

You can `chunk_while` each pair of elements are equal:

```
p array.chunk_while { |a, b| a == b }.to_a
# [[1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [5, 5], [1, 1, 1], [3, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```

You select the arrays with 3 or more elements.

After that, with `then`, you can *yield self*, so you have access to the array of arrays, which you can use to get the `starting_index`:

```
[1,2,2,2,2,5,5,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2].chunk_while(&:==).then do |this|
  this.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(e, memo), index|
    memo << { starting_index: this.to_a[0...index].flatten.size, value: e.first, length: e.size }
  end
end.select { |e| e[:length] > 3 }

# [{:starting_index=>1, :value=>2, :length=>4},
#  {:starting_index=>10, :value=>3, :length=>4},
#  {:starting_index=>14, :value=>2, :length=>7}]
```

For the starting_index, you get the elements to the current index (non inclusive), flatten them, and get the total of elements.

The value, as each array in the array has the same elements, can be anything, the length, is the length of the current array in the "main" array.

Comment: starting index is wrong as it should be based on the index in the original array per the OP.

Comment: Fixed, thanks @engineersmnky, I hadn't realized that.

Answer (score 2):

This is another option..

- Zipping the array ([Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip)) with its indexes by [Endles Ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges)
- Calling [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) (another flavour of `chunk_while`)
- Mapping ([Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)) to the required Hash
- Finally rejecting ([Enumerable#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)) hashes if `length` is greater than `3`

---

```
array
     .zip(0..)
     .slice_when { |a, b| a.first != b.first }
     .map { |a| { starting_index: a.first.last, value: a.first.first, length: a.size } }
     .reject { |h| h[:length] < 3 }

#=> [{:starting_index=>1, :value=>2, :length=>4}, {:starting_index=>7, :value=>1, :length=>3}, {:starting_index=>10, :value=>3, :length=>4}, {:starting_index=>14, :value=>2, :length=>7}]
```

Comment: Since I have noticed your shining to 2.6 methods (specifically `then`), this `array.zip((0...array.size))` can just be `array.zip(0...)` thanks to [Endless Ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html#class-Range-label-Endless+Ranges)

Comment: @engineersmnky :) Picked up!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most obvious (and probably the fastest) way is iterate over an array and count everything manually:

```rb
array = [1,2,2,2,2,5,5,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
array_length_pred = array.length.pred

consecutive_numbers = []

starting_index = 0
value = array.first
length = 1

array.each_with_index do |v, i|
  if v != value || i == array_length_pred
    length += 1 if i == array_length_pred && value == v

    if length >= 3
      consecutive_numbers << {
        starting_index: starting_index,
        value: value,
        length: length
      }
    end

    starting_index = i
    value = v
    length = 1
    next
  end

  length += 1
end

p consecutive_numbers

# [{:starting_index=>1, :value=>2, :length=>4},
# {:starting_index=>7, :value=>1, :length=>3},
# {:starting_index=>10, :value=>3, :length=>4},
# {:starting_index=>14, :value=>2, :length=>7}]
```

Comment: As I said, this is the most obvious way. It's not about _style_, it's about problem solving and performance (2.5x - 3.5x faster compared to other answers atm).

Comment: When you see how good people are in C they are measured by how good they are using their logic in their program, when you see how good people are in Ruby, It is to see how good they are at using predefined functions. Ruby has been designed that way.

Comment: It all depends on your needs, if you don't care about performance, then of course, go with that pretty one line code, otherwise, what would you do? Ruby doesn't force you to use predefined methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with strings instead.

Here, I coerce the array into a string:

```
input_sequence = [1,2,2,2,2,5,5,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2].join
```

I use a regex to group consecutive characters:

```
groups = input_sequence.gsub(/(.)\1*/).to_a
#=> ["1", "2222", "55", "111", "3333", "2222222"]
```

Now I can search for the groups as substrings within the input string:

```
groups.map do |group|
  {
    starting_index: input_sequence.index(group), 
    value: group[0].to_i,
    length: group.length
  }
end.reject { |group| group[:length] <= 3 }

#=> [{:starting_index=>1, :value=>2, :length=>4},
     {:starting_index=>7, :value=>1, :length=>3},
     {:starting_index=>10, :value=>3, :length=>4},
     {:starting_index=>14, :value=>2, :length=>7}]
```

There's room for improvement here -- I'm creating lots of intermediate objects for one -- but I thought I would offer a different approach.

Comment: There might be problems with this approach if there is a number greater than 9, or a float, wouldn't there?

Comment: @ecki, you are a master of understatement. You forgot to mention negative numbers, btw.